# How is the method read() in FileReader moving through a file?

Tags: java, file, io

So I just wrote a program that reads a specific file and returns the frequency of each character used. This was done by using a singly linked list(not java LinkedList, but very similar). What I want to know is why this:

```
 while(txtFile.read() != -1){
             Character letter = (char) txtFile.read();
             freqBag.add(Character.toLowerCase(letter));
        }
```

doesn't work(it doesn't return the correct frequency of the given character), and why this:

```
 int c;
 while((c = txtFile.read()) != -1){
             Character letter = (char) c;
             freqBag.add(Character.toLowerCase(letter));
        }
```

works. I wrote the first one, and a friend helped me fix it.

Comment: Neither of them works. They both only process the even-numbered characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're discarding characters. Each read() function brings back the next byte (as a signed int), so your code is dropping every even character (0, 2, 4...).

```
while(txtFile.read() != -1){        // Read and discard a character
    Character letter = (char) txtFile.read();  // Read a character into letter
    reqBag.add(Character.toLowerCase(letter)); // Store this letter
}
```

Your friend's code shouldn't be working either:

```
int c;           // variable outside the loop
while((c = txtFile.read()) != -1){  // Read a character into c, compare to -1
    Character letter = (char) txtFile.read();  // Read another character
    freqBag.add(Character.toLowerCase(letter));  // Store this letter
}
```

The correct method would be to read just once:

```
int c;
while((c = txtFile.read()) != -1) {
    freqBag.add(Character.toLowerCase((char)c));
}
```

I suspect either you have a typo, or you used a different file and didn't realize that letters were still being dropped.

Comment: Oh, yeah it was a typo.It works when Character letter = (char) c;. Thanks for the explanantion!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to keep in mind that when you call read method you already read one byte from file, so if you do it inside of your while statement you lose one byte.

Second thing is that for me (considering operators precedence) this two pieces of code does exact same thing so the problem might be in other part of code.